# Generating an animation from a sprite image?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I've seen the [Sublime Text website](http://www.sublimetext.com/) they have an animation that seems to be using a bunch of "sprites". How does an image like this:

[image]

become an animation? I did a couple of Google searches and most of them (the animations) are just [flattened images](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5096013/demos/cjs_spritesheets/robot2.png) which become animated images [like this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5096013/demos/cjs_spritesheets/spritesheet_canvas.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon Skinner (yes, from Sublime Text), wrote a blog post about exactly how he animated the sublime text homepage: http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html

He says he did a series of screenshots saved to .png.

Then he encoded the png's into a delta-sheet (a sprite sheet that only contains the pixel differences between the last frame and the current frame) -- quite nice and efficient!

He even gives you code for the encoder that builds the delta-sheet (python based):  https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the source  code of the second link you posted. The code is well documented. Here is a general explanation:

1. You have a canvas element, which is where the animation is drawn and a sprite image containing all the "frames" of the animation.
2. You have a "loop" function, which is being called on a set interval (in our case 1000/30 which equals 33ms)
3. The function clears the canvas element
4. The function sets an area of the sprite imgae to be drawn next. This is our "frame".
5. The function draws the calculated area of the sprite on the canvas element

I would go about doing this in a different way though. For compatibility reasons it is better to implement such kind of animations with a simple div. Just set the image sprite as a background image. Than create the very same loop, which calculates "background-position" values, which correspond to the new frame.